# Why I was not awarder silver “Census” badge after completing the Developer Survey 2017

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I completed the [Developer Survey 2017](https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk/r/VCLBYTL) successfully. I followed all steps correctly as per the instruction and finally it also displayed that I will be awarded with silver “Census” badge, but I was not awarded. Why?

Comment: The badges are awarded manually, so it may take some time until you get yours.

Comment: Happy to know this, actually I was little bit curious that why I didn't got the badge even after completing such a long survey :-D

Comment: @Floem Is it normal to *still* not receive the badge at this point? I still haven't gotten mine and it's 2/5/17 now.

Comment: even I haven't received it yet